# Error in doinbackground method

Tags: android, android-studio

I am testing an app to retrieve data to my listview from parse.com
I have no errors in my code but on running the app closes saying "unfortunately app has stopped"
This is my log cat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-02 17:14:54.050 13134 13185 E   AndroidRuntime Process: com.mycompany.myapp2, PID: 13134


11-02 17:14:54.050 13134 13185 E   AndroidRuntime   java.lang.RuntimeException: An erroroccured while executing doInBackground()


11-02 17:14:54.050 13134 13185 E   AndroidRuntime. at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
```

**my doinbackground method**

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void[] p1)
    {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("country");
        query.addDescendingOrder("_created_at");
        try{
            ob = query.find();
        }catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            
        }
        return null;
        
    }
```

**I used the this link for my code as it is**
[Link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/)

**parseapplication.java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
Import com.parse.*;

public class ParseApplication extends Application
{

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate();
    
    Parse.initialize(this, "9MoehuvnUJRKcvF8SL3nbW0slHHJNPJU4ONXGcD5", "kmBoHM4iwdm0YiyeR7aoMlyMgC5oh1oyTIOt34iu");
    
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL= new ParseACL();
    
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}

}
```

**main activity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.parse.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void[] p1)
    {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("country");
        query.addDescendingOrder("_created_at");
        try{
            ob = query.find();
        }catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            
        }
        return null;
        
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onPreExecute();
        
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("parsetesting");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("LOADING PLEASE WAIT");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                                           R.layout.listview_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                          SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                    i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
                               .toString());
                    // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    }

    
 
    
    
    
}
```

}

**yeah got the solution. As said by vishwajeet Singh . remove the application java did and add parse.initialize(this, you I'd, you key)in increase method of main activity below setcontentview ...?
Thanks vishwajeet Singh**

**

Comment: Is this logcat output complete? Also the _country_ in `doInBackground` is _Country_.

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? If not, please provide it.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg this is the link for logcat. http://pastebin.com/YyRZjuMr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Change your onCreate method in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
Parse.initialize(this, "9MoehuvnUJRKcvF8SL3nbW0slHHJNPJU4ONXGcD5", "kmBoHM4iwdm0YiyeR7aoMlyMgC5oh1oyTIOt34iu");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

}
```

This is the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(558): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must
>   call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the
>   Parse library.

You need to call **Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret)** in your application before you make any queries to Parse. This tells the service which app is yours. You can find the keys on your Parse Dashboard.

This blog post might be helpful: http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2013/08/14/tutorial-building-an-android-to-do-list-app-using-parse/

Comment: I have added parseapplication java file in my question have a if there is any errors

Comment: The Async Task must be called after on create method then your problem will get solved

Comment: I did add asynk task in increase. I added main activity.java in my question. Have a look

Comment: Just remove the ParseApplication.java and put the Parse.initialize(this, APP_ID,CLIENT_KEY); inside the MainActivity after the setContentView method

Comment: If you think the answer was helpful you may accept it..!!
Happy to help
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Now I have run into a new problem. Here's the link. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33564504/5524159. .please have a look and help me

Comment: @user5524159 You can get help on stack overflow but not by un-accepting someone's answers and downvoting them for the sake of a new answer...!!

Comment: It was not me who downvoted you. I am so grateful that you have helped me

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your application class to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application name="com.mycompany.myapp.ParseApplication"
```

You should also remove the `Parse.initialize()` method call in your `Activity`, and add it back to your application class.

Answer (score -1):

look at there is typo in spell of country

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Country");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: But the object I created in parse.com is also country not capital C

Comment: you are using small letter in country

Comment: The object I created on parse is also small. Letters

Answer (score -1):

As of reading your logcat log, it seems that this is your actual error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
```

As stated in

```
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseUser.checkApplicationContext(ParseUser.java:853)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:726)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentSessionToken(ParseUser.java:756)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.findFromNetworkAsync(ParseQuery.java:520)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.access$200(ParseQuery.java:77)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery$4.runOnNetworkAsync(ParseQuery.java:436)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.runCommandWithPolicyAsync(ParseQuery.java:383)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.findWithCachePolicyAsync(ParseQuery.java:447)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery$6.call(ParseQuery.java:492)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery$6.call(ParseQuery.java:490)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:643)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.parse.ParseQuery.find(ParseQuery.java:490)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.example.parselistview.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at com.example.parselistview.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-27 15:30:33.610: E/AndroidRuntime(558):      ... 5 more
```

It's always recommended to check your error log from the top down, starting by fixing the first error it reports. As for this particular one, take a look at https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#getting-started

Comment: I have added my parseapplication java file have a, look

Comment: In that case I've got no idea, never worked with parse. I think it might be that parse doesn't support multiple threads. Does this work in your main thread?

Comment: No it does not ,what shall I do. Is there any other method to retrieve data to your Textview other than using parse.com coz I am struck

Comment: I'd suggest working out your question fully, figuring out exactly what you want, and then asking it as another question here. For that, consider the following: Where do you want to retrieve it from, and what is it exactly that you want/need to retrieve? And, most importantly, why? There's plenty of ways of retrieving data over the internet, the easiest being through web requests (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Oh sorry for confusing. I have a long text containing introduction of a topic. And I don't want to add the introduction in my strings file .I want to retrieve it by adding it to parse.com. sorry once again