# Pressing home button and going back into the app causes the app to crash

Tags: android, parse-platform

A few days ago I asked a question about the app crashing when I run it. Here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33519273/5524159).

I got the problem solved but when I press the home and reopen the app it crashes saying unfortunately app has stopped. Now if I reopen the app It works but the Same happens when home button is pressed and the app is reopened . don't know what the problem is 
Here is the logcat

```
11-11 15:43:19.958 13385 13385 D   AndroidRuntime  Shutting down VM
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 13385
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:39)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:153)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:191)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
11-11 15:43:19.994 13385 13385 E   AndroidRuntime  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
//Note that this is an android.app.Application class.
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

//This will only be called once in your app's entire lifecycle.
Parse.initialize(this,
        getResources().getString(R.string.parse_application_id),
        getResources().getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
    ....
    <activity>
        ....
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.**NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a **null
>   object reference**

Check your code, you're trying to call `getParseDir()` method on a **null** Object.

Comment: To avoid confusion future users, if you have another problem you should ask a new question not updating the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize Parse in your Application class, like you tried doing here:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application
{

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "9MoehuvnUJRKcvF8SL3nbW0slHHJNPJU4ONXGcD5", "kmBoHM4iwdm0YiyeR7aoMlyMgC5oh1oyTIOt34iu");
```

But for that to work, you must also specify the application class in your `AndroidManifest.xml` manually.

```
<application name="com.mycompany.myapp.ParseApplication"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer